# What are the AVFoundation AVCaptureDevice settings for the camera app on iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, camera, avcapturesession

I was wondering what the AVCaptureDevice settings are for the camera app on iPhone. Specifically the AVCaptureExposureMode, AVCaptureFocusMode, and AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode. I am trying to make a custom camera and for some reason I can't get the lighting of the photo to change correctly on focusing. I set the ExposurePointOfInterest and the FocusPointOfInterest for my camera, but for some reason it seems as though the camera focuses correctly but the lighting doesn't focus where I tap. When I tap on a dark area it doesn't lighten up like in the camera app. Is there some setting that I'm forgetting to set? Here is my code for focusing the camera.

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:collectView];
float focus_x = touchPoint.x / collectView.frame.size.width;
float focus_y = touchPoint.y / collectView.frame.size.height;
NSError *tError = nil;
NSLog(@"previous: %.2f, %.2f", backCamera.focusPointOfInterest.x, backCamera.focusPointOfInterest.y);
if (isFrontCamera) {
    focus_x = collectView.frame.size.width - focus_x; //the view is mirrored for the front camera
    if ([frontCamera lockForConfiguration:&tError]) {
        if ([frontCamera isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]) {
            [frontCamera setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)];
            if ([frontCamera isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]) {
                [frontCamera setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }
        }
        if ([frontCamera isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
            [frontCamera setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)];
            if ([frontCamera isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]) {
                [frontCamera setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }
        }
        if ([frontCamera isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance]) {
            [frontCamera setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance];
        }
        [frontCamera unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't change focus point:%@",tError);
    }
}
else {
    if ([backCamera lockForConfiguration:&tError]) {
        if ([backCamera isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]) {
            [backCamera setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)];
            if ([backCamera isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]) {
                [backCamera setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }
        }
        if ([backCamera isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
            [backCamera setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)];
            if ([backCamera isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
                [backCamera setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            }
        }
        if ([backCamera isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance]) {
            [backCamera setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance];
        }
        [backCamera unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't change focus point:%@",tError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) has many things in it and will partially answer your question.

Hope this helps a bit as we can not tell every properties' value for the Camera app.